# Wrong direction results from r.horizon, raster mode in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin

I perform the algorithm r.horizon, raster mode using QGIS 3.28.15, I used always to check the flag `-c` and set it to `true`, because I am interested in compass direction clockwise (so North is at 0 degrees, East 90 degrees and so on) until I noticed something not expected in shadow when visualizing the results in QGIS, so I took an small DEM containing an Island for test purpose then I performed `r.horizon` raster mode twice, first time with setting flag `-c` to `true` and second time let it set to `false`, just to spare time I set step 90 direction from 0 to 360, so 4 rasters should be as output.

I compared those results, they all are the same without any change in direction eventhought I did it once with `-c` set `true` and other time `false`.

I doubted if I checked the `-c` flag, so I opened the history log and indeed everything done as I entered without any typo.

I will share the illustrations here just for direction 0 and 90, can one explain why the expected results (shown with green arrows) not calculated as expected?

All the 8 result rasters for both cases and plus the DEM used are available here, almost 150 Kb zipped file:
[data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DfIZSse17NhHhYYglQjv1CrH-3PzVZUI/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

**In the documentation:**

[image]

**My history log:**

[image]

Comment: Per https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/r.horizon.html `-c
    Write output in compass orientation (default is CCW, East=0)` (not North=0 and not clockwise). Check your version number? r.horizon is a GRASS GIS thing, even though QGIS uses it

Comment: exactly in this url stands "Using the -c flag, the azimuthal angles will be printed in compass orientation (North=0, clockwise)." and I posted it in question as screenshot.

Comment: Either if there is missunderstanding or not, I made two call, once set it false, another set it true, and as illustrated, same result